# How to deal with changes within a project with 2 versions?

Tags: java, migration

here I present you my problem: There is a Java project, a part of it is split into microservices. These microservices were written using spring boot 2.5. I am migrating them to spring boot 3.1. Until everything is migrated and we will release this version in production, problems are resolved, changes are made on the initial version (which uses spring boot 3).

BUT, then I have to get these changes on the branches that are already migrated. Is there a way to get notified when some changes are merged into the current dev branch? Like, "these files just got modified". Or to somehow apply these changes on both branches (dev and springboot3 branch)? we work with bitbucket.